# configure postfix to send mail only to known adresses

Tags: postfix

I am using postfix to relay my emails from *@myyyrd.fr to specific recipients:

```
#/etc/aliases
aXXXXre:        aXXXXd@gmail.com
aXXe:           ahXXXX@gmail.com
aXXXs:          mXXXs@hotmail.com
vXXXXXt:        mXXXX@hotmail.fr

#/etc/reg_aliases
/.*/    aXXXXd@gmail.com
```

I would like to prevent the use of my postfix server as spam relay and therefose prevent the server to send outgoing email to all but the list of adresses described above.

In order to be clear, an email send to toto@myyyrd.fr would be **redirected** to aXXXXd@gmail.com but and email send to aYYYY@gmail.com should be **rejected**.

I tried without success to use /etc/postfix/transport and /etc/postfix/access...

## postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, regexp:/etc/reg_aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, melard.fr
myorigin = melard.fr
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: It would be great if you post the output of `postconf -n`, so our fellow reader can figure what's wrong with postfix configuration :)

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, the default configuration of postfix should be enough to prevent usage of your server as an open relay.
This is due to the parameter `smtpd_relay_restrictions`, which conditions acceptance of all mails to either it being intended to a local recipient (prior to aliasing), authenticated using sasl or generated localy (by default).

If you really need to restrict more specifically, you can use the directive `check_recipient_access` in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`. It allows you to configure a file with the list of accepted address.

Comment: I've tried the use of that parameter, the thing is that, imo, it checks incoming email addresses and not outgoing email addresses.

Comment: the smtpd_relay_restrictions parameter is NOT defined in my conf, which is mostly genuine.

Comment: @AlexandreMélard It has a default value, see `postconf smtpd_relay_restrictions`.

Comment: Thanks, I read the manual after reading your answer. I still have spam sent from my account, my ismp has blocked my IP on port 25 because of that... That's why I am trying to enforce the security on my server.

Comment: @AlexandreMélard Indeed, it checks incoming email destination adresses, such as toto@myyyrd.fr in your example. imo, it seems to be the most reasonnable way to do what you want, though you could indeed try to tweek a transport-map into rejecting email.

Comment: @AlexandreMélard Do you have any log or evidence on how those mails are generated ? Are you sure they transit to your postfix host ? If so, how are they bypassing `smtpd_relay_restrictions` ?

Comment: I guess I'm sending spam or my ISMP would not have banned my IP. I'll try to get some evidences